# General questions about Fido UAF

Tags: authentication, client, authenticator, fido, uaf

I recently found FIDO UAF architecture and i'm currently trying to implement it. However there are some questions that i can't find the answer and i really need somenone to explain me. It is making me crazy since i don't understand the main concepts.

1 - What is an authenticator?
I have an OnePlus 3. It has fingerprint sensor and i can access it via Fingerprint API. Is that an authenticator? Do i have to pay something in order to have an aaid?

2 - What is an ASM?
I'm developing my app in C# so if i create a C# class called ASM am i doing it correctly?

3 - How can i obtain aaid?
How do i know the aaid of my OnePlus 3?

4 -  I read that some smartphones have FIDO Client already implemented? How do i know if my OnePlus 3 have?

Sorry my dummy questions. It may probably make no sense for you but as you can see i'm not understanding the concepts of FIDO UAF.
Many thanks to everyone.

Comment: Your question doesn’t look like related to programming directly, so please consider using another site for this.

Comment: @Ricardo: \You can answer your questions, which may be helpful for us. Pls :)

Comment: I still don't know the answer :D